# How to Display Skip Button to close the MPmoviePlayerViewController at 10 Secs of playing Video

Tags: objective-c, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, nstimer, mpmovieplayer

In my app Im playing an video using MPmoviePlayerViewController.

actually some videos are too long to watch around 3-5 mins.

I want to allow user to **SKIP the video after 10 seconds if he wants**.

**My requirement is
I need to display the count down 10, 9, 8 -- 0 after 10th secod of the the video we display a skip button.**

```
_moviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] init ];
    [_moviePlayerViewController.view setFrame:self.view.frame];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:_moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];


    _moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [_moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES];
    _moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeNone;
    _moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    _moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeNone;
    _moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.contentURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
```

in this application we have play back option,
ie if the user quit the application he can resume the video from the point of going background.

```
in both the case (resume after come foreground, and just now started video)
the user should see a skip button when the video play time is 10 seconds.
```

Can any one help please

Comment: Setup a timer, then have your button `setVisible = True` on 10 secs or, to show a counter, have the display change every sec then, after 10 secs, `setActive = True`

Answer (score 1):

What the problem? Use `dispatch_after` for 5 seconds pause then inside dispatch block run one second timer to count seconds remaining

**EDIT**
Oh I'm sorry, you need just one `NSTimer` and seconds counter ivar to track how many seconds passed from the video start

Answer (score 1):

For playback option you can use `[_moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer pause];` when going in background and can again resume play from where it was when again come to foreground.

In case if user quit application you can provide playback option also. You can manage a counter variable separately, which count for how seconds the video is playing. Store the value of this counter when user quit application, in short store the value when player stops playing. Now when you again come back to this view you can check the actual length of video and compare with the duration for which it has already played and play back.This can be tricky but the pause thing mentioned above did work.
EDIT: For hiding and displaying skip button after 10sec the counter solution is perfect.